# Firefox getting stuck on opening/closing tabs

Tags: windows, firefox

Using Firefox (both the regular version and Firefox Portable with Firefox Portable 2nd Profile) on Win 10 64-bit - in multiple computers, it seemingly randomly gets stuck when opening or closing tabs. Once it happens, the only way around it is to force close Firefox entirely, which loses everything one does.

Is there any way to catch these errors within Firefox and investigate them? Windows' Event Manager only catches the manual force close:

> ### Error 1002, Application Hang
>
> The program firefox.exe version 54.0.1.6388 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
>
> Process ID: 1bcc
>
> Start Time: 01d2f25179997c37
>
> Termination Time: 11
>   Application Path: ...\firefox.exe
>
> Report Id: 3c32ddc4-9e2e-41b8-b01f-6bc804782ef0
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Followed by:

> ### Event 1001, Windows Error Reporting
>
> Fault bucket , type 0
>
> Event Name: AppHangB1
>
> Response: Not available
>
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
>
> P1: firefox.exe
>
> P2: 54.0.1.6388
>
> P3: 5953d2cc
>
> P4: e7d5
>
> P5: 134217728
>
> P6:
>
> P7:
>
> P8:
>
> P9:
>
> P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD2E7.tmp.csv
>
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD307.tmp.txt
>
> \?...\AppData\Local\Temp\WERDE44.tmp.appcompat.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppHang_firefox.exe_e0711f97c7d4d761f4fcad6ffbfb1bf705029b8_4f6c277d_172ef360
>
> Analysis symbol:
>
> Rechecking for solution: 0
>
> Report Id: d204ee39-106b-47f2-a10f-37569d17d5fa
>
> Report Status: 97
>
> Hashed bucket:

Comment: Why not you use the official Firefox browser?

Comment: Why use PortableApps for any app, for that matter? Because it keeps my system fast and clean. And as mentioned, we don't know if it's related to the issue.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect is also happens in the regular version in multiple computers.

Comment: Are you using any extensions or plugins? Usually it's good idea to try with a fresh profile. If it doesn't happen with a fresh profile (without extensions etc.) you know it's likely not related to the software itself.

Comment: In one of the profiles I have just plugins that were installed by default (OpenH264 & Wildvine) and the only extension is Selenium.